# Fibonacci... Easier by induction or directly via Binet's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

[image]

I have tried both for several of them and haven't been able to get anywhere in 3 hours of work. It seems to not matter which method I choose, I end up in the middle of a HUGE mess of algebra. Could someone please shed some light?

Note(Binet's formula for $k^{th}$ fib. element):$\ \ \ \ \ $ $f_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(  \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k - \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^k \right)$

Comment: The first is very straightforward to prove by induction on $n$. What happens if you add $f_{n+1}$ to both sides of (a)?

Comment: The second and third look like candidates for Binet's formula.  Plug in the indices and see if things work out.  I'll bet so.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks brian, you get the sum of $f_{k+1}$ on the LHS and since $f_0 = 0$, we technically get the sum of $f_{k}$ from 0 to n+1. On the RHS, we get $f_{n+2} + f_{n+1} = f_{n+3}$ by fib, and then the -1 of course. Thanks

Comment: As for the second and third, I have tried plugging in binet and doing the algebra, but I just get lost in a big mess. Do you have any tips?

Comment: I don’t immediately see anything nice, but I’ll tinker with it for a while.

Comment: If you use Binet, which would not be my choice, let $\tau=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then the other one is $-\frac{1}{\tau}$. Work with these symbols, not with their ugly versions. Things will look much cleaner.

Comment: André, does that give $f_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \tau^{k} - \left( \frac{1}{\tau} \right)^{k} \right)\ $ or$\ $ $+$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving (b) or (c) individually might be easier using Binet's formula. But proving (b) and (c) together is very easy using induction (technically strong induction, since the inductive step for $f_n$ will use the conclusions for both $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$); just do cases depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

If you want to use Binet's formula (for (b) say), start from
\begin{align*}
f_{n+1}^2 &= \frac15 \bigg( \bigg( \frac{1+\sqrt5}2 \bigg)^{2n+2} -2(-1)^{n+1} + \bigg( \frac{1-\sqrt5}2 \bigg)^{2n+2} \bigg) \\
f_n^2 &= \frac15 \bigg( \bigg( \frac{1+\sqrt5}2 \bigg)^{2n} -2(-1)^{n} + \bigg( \frac{1-\sqrt5}2 \bigg)^{2n} \bigg)
\end{align*}
and combine the first terms with each other (by factoring out $((1+\sqrt5)/2)^2$ from the first term, for example); you should get what you need.

Comment: I have $\ f_{2n+1} = \left( \frac{\varphi^{n+1} - \left( \frac{1}{\varphi} \right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\varphi^{n} - \left( \frac{1}{\varphi} \right)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}} \right)^2\ $ Does this look right?